# ObjectContext .CreateDatabaseScript() Ignores some entities although they are mapped correctly

Tags: entity-framework-4, objectcontext

`CreateDatabaseScript()` method of `ObjectContext`, generate string containing script to create the desired database, but it ignores some entities with its related FKs

When I look into the script, I found something like this

```
-- Ignoring entity set with defining query: [FMISDomainModelEFStoreContainer].[Ex_Students]

-- Ignoring association set with participating entity set with defining query: [FK_Ex_Students_City]
```

Is there a problem in my model? although it is validated correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, Sorry I found it, in XML of the entity model this error

```
Errors Found During Generation:
      warning 6002: The table/view 'FMIS.dbo.MyTableName' does not have a primary key defined. The key has been inferred and the definition was created as a read-only table/view.
```

I think that's why it is not generated in StorageModel of my model

Comment: :) But how to solve that? this is weird, in ConceptualModel there is a PK for these tables, and also in the StorageModel also.